jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Button') TypeError
Background -
I am trying to use react inside Spring MVC application and for that I have installed react libs using
npm init -y
npm install react react-dom
npm install webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server babel-loader
npm intall react-bootstap bootstrap

Getting Below error in dev tools console when I am trying to add React Boootstrap elements in my Component.jsx
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Button') TypeError
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";

function Component() {

const [count,setCount] = React.useState(0)
const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState({});

const handleChange = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputs(values => ({...values, [name]: value}))
}


 function incrementCount(){
setCount((prevoiuseCount) => prevoiuseCount+1)
   }

return(
    <div><h1>You clicked me {count} times </h1>
    <button onClick={incrementCount}> Click me</button>
    <div style={{marginLeft: "-1301px"}}>
        <Button></Button>
    </div>
    <div style={{marginTop: "-16px"}}>
        <hr style={{borderTop: "2px solid"}}></hr>
    </div>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><label>Account Number :</label></td>
                <td><input
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    value={inputs.username || ""}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                /></td>
            </tr></tbody>

        </table>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit"  className="btn btn-primary"/>

    </form>

</div>);
}
export default Component`

I am expecting to use react bootstrap component in jsx files. Please assist on this.

The issue might be related to installation of react-bootstrap
I would delete node_modules folder, reopen my editor and do npm install
